# Migrating old Addons to NAPI

Tags: node.js-addon, node.js-nan, node.js-napi

I'm new to Node.js addons, I don't understand the difference between `nan` and `n-api`.

And is there an easy way to migrate an addon for old version (node v.0) to a newer version (node v.8)?

Answer (score 2):

`n-api` is a new way to create addon independent from the underlying JavaScript runtime (ex V8) and is maintained as part of Node.js.

I think there is no easy way for migration to n-api because it changed almost every interface but I think programming with `n-api` is easier than `nan`. In `n-api` you can use pure C programming and it's new feature. for more example on `n-api` you can check [here](https://github.com/1995parham/Napi101).

Comment: The n-api api has changed since your wrote that code which is confusing

Comment: @simon-p-r thanks for mentioning that, I will update my code.

Comment: Hi Parham, do you think this method is possible inside **electron** too? If so, can you give me a hint?... thank you

Comment: @Prak I think you can use it, you simply create a native module like my GitHub example and use its API in your electron code. just check your node version before using n-API.